# Additional model validation

Tags: c#, validation

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(LongUrlModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var baseAddress = Request.RequestUri.ToString().TrimEnd('/');
        if (model.LongUrl.StartsWith(baseAddress))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "You cant shorten a URL that belongs to this domain");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        *snip*
    }
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

I am not at all fond of the conditional logic here, it can be quite hard to follow. How can I refactor the additional model validation logic so that it will co-exist with the standard model validation nicely?

I feel as though there could be a way to refactor this code so that  `Request.CreateErrorResponse` only occurs in the code once, but I cannot see how at the moment.

Comment: what does *snip* mean?  And also, is this a MVC WebApi project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to your question:

> I feel as though there could be a way to refactor this code so that
>   `Request.CreateErrorResponse` only occurs in the code once, but I cannot
>   see how at the moment.

I would consider reducing the nesting (Arrow code) of the If statements and perform follow the return early mantra.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(LongUrlModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var baseAddress = Request.RequestUri.ToString().TrimEnd('/');
    if (model.LongUrl.StartsWith(baseAddress))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You cant shorten a URL that belongs to this domain");
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // Perform the valid code logic here
}

private HttpResponseMessage BadRequest()
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

In regards to your other question

> I am not at all fond of the conditional logic here

There's a few things I can think of you could try.

1. Create a custom validation attribute and decorate the `LongUrl` property.

   ```
     public class UrlLengthAttribute: ValidationAttribute
     {
         public UrlLengthAttribute()
         {
         }

         protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
           var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
           var url = value as string;

           if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace())
           {
             return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
           }

           // I'm not 100% on this code but you get the general idea
           var baseAddress = httpContext.RequestUri.ToString().TrimEnd('/');

           if(url.StartsWith(baseAddress))
           {
             return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
           }

           return null;
         }
     }
   ```

You can then use this to decorate your model:

```
    public class LongUrlModel
    {
        [UrlLength(ErrorMessage = "You cant shorten a URL that belongs to this   domain")]    
        public string LongUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

1. You could the extract the model validation out into a separate Validator class and use that in the controller instead.  At the very least it might be moving towards the lines of creating a unit testable module.

   ```
     public class LongUrlModelValidator
     {
        public LongUrlModelValidator(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
         // store and use
        }

        public bool Validate(LongUrlModel model)
        {
         // perform validation logic here
        }
     }
   ```

Comment: Thanks bro. You couldn't have known this, but I am using Web API 2 so I used the standard `BadRequest` method. I also reduced the nesting like you suggested. A custom validation attribute is a nice idea, as is a validator class, but as the validation is only required in one place (the aforementioned action) I do not feel as though the ROI makes it worthwhile.

Comment: @CasterTroy ah ok, fair enough.  The only other suggestion then is perhaps moving that validation to a private method within the controller i.e. if(IsShortUrlRequest()) return BadRequest()